# Iterate over Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a Javascript object

```
var a = {
    "tag1": "Stocks",
    "acctType1": "individual",
    "compare1": "contains",
    "match_name1": "scrapedaccounttype",
    "text1": "dog ",
    "tag2": "Stocks",
    "acctType2": "individual",
    "compare2": "contains",
    "match_name2": "scrapedaccounttype",
    "text2": "cat"
}
```

I need to use this Javascript object to do some more math, but I am not sure about how I would be iterating over the Javascript object.

I can have any number of tags `(tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4 ... )` or similarly other keys like `(acctType1, acctType2, acctType3.... )`  so I need to iterate over them individually and do some manipulation to use these variables in a different function.

While , for each what would help my cause here. Note that I could have any number of `tags(tag1,tag2...)` or `comapare(compare1, compare2, compare3..)`

I would need to process all of them individually.

Comment: You didn't search a lot, did you ?

Comment: I already saw that question confusing syntax bro :)

Comment: @rahul888 Searching the title of your question brings *many* other questions. If you're confused by one, look for the other ones...

Comment: _"I have a Json object or string"_ - [No you don't](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), you have an object. All JSON is a string, and there is no JSON in your question.

Comment: Tidied up a bit for you, take more pride in your question and you may get a better response.

Answer (score 3):

What you have **is NOT** JSON. It is JavaScript defining an [Object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals), commonly referred to as a JS object. JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a string that can be parsed to produce an object literal.

For your JS object (which has [ample online documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)), you can iterate over the object keys by:

```
var a={"tag1":"Stocks","acctType1":"individual","compare1":"contains","match_name1":"scrapedaccounttype","text1":"dog ","tag2":"Stocks","acctType2":"individual","compare2":"contains","match_name2":"scrapedaccounttype","text2":"cat"}

Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
  console.log(a[k]);
});
```

Or:

```
for (var key in a) {
  if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(a[k]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend the latter option